# Outlook Exchange & Embedded Styles on mobile HTML email

Tags: android, iphone, html, email, exchange-server

I am seeing something very strange when using embedded <style> tags inside HTML email that I am opening on mobile devices.  Usually, embedded styles inside <style> tag are rendered, except in the two nearly-identical cases.

(All of these use cases are about receiving email in the phone's native mail app, not via the mobile browser, and not via the Gmail mail application on Android.)

<style> tags **are correctly rendered** in the following cases:

- iPhone Mail, receiving email on the @gmail.com domain
- iPhone Mail, receiving email on the @yahoo.com domain
- iPhone Mail, receiving email on the @live.com domain
- iPhone Mail, receiving email on our company's domain, an MS Exchange mail account
- Android Email (Froyo), receiving email on the @gmail.com domain
- Android Email (Froyo), receiving email on the @yahoo.com domain
- Android Email (Froyo), receiving email on the @live.com domain
- Palm OS, receiving email on the @gmail.com domain
- Palm OS, receiving email on the @yahoo.com domain
- Palm OS, receiving email on the @live.com domain

<style> tags **are NOT correctly rendered** (at all -- as if they are stripped out completely) in the following cases:

- Android Email (Froyo), receiving email on our company's domain, an MS Exchange mail account
- Palm OS, receiving email on our company's domain, an MS Exchange mail account

So, this is strange.  It means the problem in those failed cases is not simply one of these pieces:

1. Exchange server (it renders the <style> tags when opening mail on iPhone)
2. Android Email  (it renders the <style> tags in many scenarios)
3. Palm OS  (it renders the <style> tags in many scenarios)

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why those particular combos might fail?

Does the iPhone somehow retrieve HTML email from Exchange in a manner totally different from Android Email and Palm OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a known issue.  At least on Android anyway, which is all I can refer to.

The native Android email app will NOT render HTML emails when using Exchange ActiveSync.  Something to do with how the email is requested from the server.

Most people are using Touchdown as a replacement, but IMHO it has it's problems.

Do a quick search on Google for 'android html activesync' and you'll find heaps of people whinging about it not working.